# How to reorder rows in a qplot (R)

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I create a colored grid using this script:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
sum<-c(0.58,0.65,0.58,0.53,0.41,0.37)
len<-c(0.24,0.36,0.24,0.21,0.07,0.12)
mean<-c(0.83,0.81,0.83,0.83,0.80,0.75)
cl2<-c(0.73,0.75,0.73,0.62,0.60,0.54)
X<-c("het1","het3","het5","het7","het10","het15")
df<-data.frame(X,sum,len,mean,cl2)
a<-melt(df)
names(a)<-c("het","variables","Correlation")
qplot(variables, het, fill=Correlation, data=a,geom='tile')
```

Which produce this figure:

[image]

As you can see in the figure, rows of the y axis are not correctly sorted. I would need to sort this to get `het1`, `het3`, `het5`, `het7`, `het10` and `het15` in the correct order. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just relevel the factor before you create the plot:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
sum<-c(0.58,0.65,0.58,0.53,0.41,0.37)
len<-c(0.24,0.36,0.24,0.21,0.07,0.12)
mean<-c(0.83,0.81,0.83,0.83,0.80,0.75)
cl2<-c(0.73,0.75,0.73,0.62,0.60,0.54)
X<-c("het1","het3","het5","het7","het10","het15")
df<-data.frame(X,sum,len,mean,cl2)
a<-melt(df)

names(a)<-c("het","variables","Correlation")
a$het = factor(a$het, levels = X)
qplot(variables, het, fill=Correlation, data=a,geom='tile')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, but I still getting the same row order: het1 het10 het15 het3 het5 het7... What I need is het1 het3 het5 het7 het10 het15...

Comment: Did you re-run the entire code? When I run this code it produces the y-axis ordering you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry. The ordering is wrong. Re-level after the names(a) statement. I've edited the answer.

Comment: The reason this works is that the factor levels correspond to how the categorical variable is plotted. If you want to relevel the column "het" you need to have already named the column "het". This is why it has to be after the names(a) statement.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I have a last question. I want to have a colour scale fixed from 0 to 1 independently of what the matrix data is (which is going to be always between those limits). I want this in order to be able to compare graphs. I have been trying different things to this but nothing worked. Can you give me some tips?

Comment: Glad it worked. Check out the ggplot2 documentation for color scales. You can do it like this: qplot(variables, het, fill=Correlation, data=a,geom='tile') + scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(0, 1)). If this (and the actual answer above) solved your question, please accept the answer so someone who stumbles across this page will easily see there is a solution.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thanks again. Sorry, how can I accept the answer?